# Redis SLAVE flushes data when MASTER goes down

Tags: redis, replication

I have commented the "save" commands in both my master and slave as I want to do only in memory caching and not persist to the file. This works fine but as soon as the Master goes down and before Slave can be promoted  to master ( It actually freezes for a min ) it starts flushing the data. How can I prevent the slave from flushing the data.

Thanks
zafer

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the slave does not flush the data when the master goes down.

It starts a SYNC (flushing the data before) with the master, when it has lost the connection with the master, and has established the connection again.

IMO, the problem is the master restarts immediately, so the slave can reconnect before it has been promoted to master.

You should delay the restart of the master until the slave have been promoted. Depending on how the HA is automated, it may not be very convenient. A simple (but not very reliable) solution is to just put a delay in the start script of the Redis instance. The delay should be calculated so that you are 100% sure the slave will be promoted before it times out. A more complex solution is to try to connect to the slave in the start script of the master, and run the INFO command to check its status, before allowing the start.

See the following discussion for more information:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/redis-db/wmRSuIgHcEs/discussion

Comment: Yes the master restarts immediately but is set as SLAVE too immediately. And since the slave freezes immediately after master goes down the it takes a while for it to unfreeze and be set to MASTER, by that time I guess it is too late. Will try the options you suggested. Thanks